# передача родительского элемента

Tags: javascript, button

у меня есть несколько родительских элементов и внутри них несколько объектов, включая кнопку. суть вопроса: как при нажатии на кнопку получить доступ к блоку с классом `bottom`, чтобы сменить ему стиль? можно ли как то в `onclick` передать значение, чтобы не создавать кучу переменных в js под каждую кнопку и блок?

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.top p {
  width: 50%;
}

.top button {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.bottom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button>&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button>&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button>&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.block .top button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.closest('.block').querySelector('.bottom').classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.top p {
  width: 50%;
}

.top button {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.bottom {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button>&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>111 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button>&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>222 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button>&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>333 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

пока ждал, ещё один вариант придумал

```js
function Open(e) {
  let one = e.parentNode;
  let two = one.parentNode;
  let bottom = two.getElementsByClassName('bottom').item(0);
  bottom.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.top p {
  width: 50%;
}

.top button {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.bottom {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button onclick="Open(this)">&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button onclick="Open(this)">&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <button onclick="Open(this)">&#43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```